# Prometheus alert rules - check if a label exists in the message field

Tags: devops, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

An example of the rule I want to append with a label if that label exists.

```yaml
- alert: TargetDown
      annotations:
        message: '{{`{{`}} printf "%.4g" $value {{`}}`}}% of the {{`{{`}} $labels.job {{`}}`}}/{{`{{`}} $labels.service {{`}}`}} targets in {{`{{`}} $labels.namespace {{`}}`}} namespace are down.'
```

I want to be able to append pod name with `$labels.pod` to the message string. So ideally it would look like:

```yaml
- alert: TargetDown
      annotations:
        message: '{{`{{`}} printf "%.4g" $value {{`}}`}}% of the {{`{{`}} $labels.job {{`}}`}}/{{`{{`}} $labels.service {{`}}`}} targets in namesapce {{`{{`}} $labels.namespace {{`}}`}} in pod {{`{{`}} $labels.pod {{`}}`}} are down.'
```

So there I added `` in pod {{`{{`}} $labels.pod {{`}}`}} ``. But some matches won't have pod labels. I want to change that appended piece of string and print pod label only if it exists. I couldn't find any documentation about it. I saw something like `{{if eq ($value) "2"}} dosmth {{end}}`, but it is not what I need. I just want to say; okay if `$labels.pod` exists then print `` in pod {{`{{`}} $labels.pod {{`}}`}} ``. Otherwise don't add that to the message.

Comment: And besides that, what logic does Prometheus follow here? Is it the syntax some language is already using or it's natively defined by Prometehus?